# Undefined symbol error when starting LibreOffice in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: libreoffice, 20.04

After executing the command `libreoffice` I am getting the following error message.

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
```

Starting it from the desktop environment does not show anything.

I tried renaming `~/.config/libreoffice` to reset the user settings, but it did not change anything. A new `~/.config/libreoffice` folder was created, however.

I started getting this error after I had reinstalled my Ubuntu to the latest version 20.04. I kept my home folder on a separate drive intact, I just formatted the OS drive during the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `LD_PRELOAD` variable to point to a different library solved the problem. Namely, the following command worked for me.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 libreoffice
```

So to be able to run LibreOffice from the desktop environment I added an environment variable export line to `~/.profile`.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
```

This solution, however, seems hacky to me. A more proper one will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to check dynamic linking of the libraries with `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2` and `ldd /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin`. They should not contain any references to `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @N0rbert thank you for the reply. I have run those commands but found no references to `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Just guessing - do you have any freetype related libraries in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: @N0rbert my `/usr/local/lib` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on ubuntu 20.04, the error was (`undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates`)

It seems libreoffice is searching for the libfreetype from graalvm. Libreoffice stores the JAVA_HOME setting in a file called `javasettings_Linux_X86_64.xml` under `~/.config/libreoffice`

You can find it by running

```
find ~/.config/libreoffice -name javasettings_Linux_X86_64.xml
```

1- Try renaming the file and run `libreoffice --calc` the file will be generated automatically and this might work.

2- The one that worked for me is to remove `javasettings_Linux_X86_64.xml` and download java 11 and point JAVA_HOME temporary to java 11 then run `libreoffice --calc` at the time I used java 8 so a version higher might work as well but I have tried 11. I left the java 11 where it is but point JAVA_HOME back to 8 after (You can leave java 11 if you don't need current java version for other things)

In `javasettings_Linux_X86_64.xml` file there is the following:

```
<vendor>AdoptOpenJDK</vendor>
<location>file:///opt/jdk-11.0.4+11</location>
<version>11.0.4</version>
```

All seems to be working well and I hope it helps someone else.